# Coagulation of protiens of different products

Tags: biochemistry

Protein of egg coagulates on 60 degree but proteins of milk do not coagulate at high temperatures..why?
What is the main reason behind all this?

Comment: Milk coagulates at a temperature below 18 degrees is what I do know.

Comment: I'll look into it for you.